# jQuery show/get the user IP address

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

Recently, I started to learn `jQuery` and I wanted to create a simple script where you display the user IP. However, the code I wrote it is not working and sadly my knowledge is not enough to find the problem by myself. That is why if someone can help me I will be really grateful.

The code:

```js
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#IP_Address').append("Your IP: " + data.query);
    $('#Country').append("Your Country: " + data.country);
    $('#City').append("Your City: " + data.city);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="IP_Address"></div>
<div id="Country"></div>
<div id="City"></div>
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: Seems to be working for me?

Comment: What output/result are you getting?

Comment: it is working correctly

Comment: Hope everything works fine. What is wrong in that ? Can you please explain your issue ?

Comment: Thanks for the `http://ip-api.com` I didnt know about it. +1

Comment: @Loading.. Yes, I thought that it will work too, but when I uploaded on my hosting it was showing a blank page. I tried with different jQuery versions but nothing has changed. Any idea where might be the problem?

Comment: @Reddy, you are welcome :)

Comment: What was the issue?  It works fine in fiddle...

Comment: @GeorgeStoyanov then we might have to look into your hosted site for providing help.. because the issue is not reproducible here

Comment: @Reddy And to all others which are following this thread, the problem came from Chrome/Opera. After trying it under Firefox it was working fine. Further investigation led that AdBlock was causing the problem. After reinstalling the extension now everything is working fine. I am really happy that so many people wanted to help. I am really grateful!!!

Best regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#IP_Address').append("Your IP: " + data.query);
    $('#Country').append("Your Country: " + data.country);
    $('#City').append("Your City: " + data.city);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="IP_Address"></div>
<div id="Country"></div>
<div id="City"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Copy all text, install WampServer in your computer and locate your folder "www", create a file pruebahtml.php, write in your web browser http://localhost/pruebahtml.php and show me

[Show me](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19N-nDOSXoQ47CINKKuMXJFqOZnfGvZpN/view?usp=sharing)